# Get response time from Gatling after reading message from a Kafka queue

Tags: apache-kafka, gatling

I have an application in which there is an https service that receives a message and there are a few microservices that process this message and at the end the message is put into a Kafka queue.
I want to know the performance of the microservices end to end.
I want to run tests and want to calculate the time difference between message sent to the http service and time message received from http Kafka queue.

Can we do this with Gatling?

Comment: Few questions:
1) When the application receives a request does it wait till the message is put into kafka before closing the http connection?
2) Does your service log in apache log format or something?
3) Can you control kafka configuration example: [acks](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#acks) and/or [queue.buffering.max.ms] because in order to truely measure the message is received and sent quickly .You can either leverage [on_delivery callback](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#pythonclient-configuration)

Comment: Resources:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/STATISTICS.md
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#pythonclient-configuration

Comment: Please use these references only(just to ignite the thought process), as  implementation in languages differ.

Comment: 1. No it doesn't wait  2.yes it does log 3. No i can't change config

Comment: One of the easiest way to achieve this would be note the time when the request was initiated, and each kafka message has a timestamp metadata. Calculate the difference the between the two. Please incorporate timezone in that calculation.

One things i will incorporate(if possible), publish message to kafka with a specific key[s] so while consuming it is easier to look for or publish to a kafka topic.

[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-MetadataResponse]